# Convert Sql row into column

Tags: sql

I have this table:

```
Value |   Name    
300   |   moshe                 
400   |   yoni   
500   |   niv
```

And i would like to convert it into this:

```
nameColumn: moshe yoni niv     
value:      300   400  500
```

The value is `float` type and name is `nchar(20)`.
anyone?
thanks

Comment: Google goes a long way. If you google with your question title, you get your solution

Comment: Tag the dbms used. (The answer will be product specific!)

Answer (score 1):

Most databases have a [PIVOT relational operator](https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177410(v=sql.105).aspx) (link for SQL Server) to turn the unique values of a specified column from multiple rows into multiple column values in the output (cross-tab), effectively rotating a table.

Comment: @Julian - with all due respect, I have been told not to include links because they can 'break' and so I don't include them.  Then I am told to include links.  So, we need this resolved going forward -- links or no links?  I'm not blaming you but it is confusing.  Who can I address to resolve this issue?  Also, I don't believe this question is specific to SQL Server and there are / were no tags stating such.  All in all, it should not be down voted.

Comment: I just added the link as additional information; you were right to post a text-based answer which did not solely consist of a link. In general, links are fine but they should only be used as a reference, rather than being presented as the answer itself. See also [help center on editing](http://stackoverflow.com/help/editing). For what it's worth, I did not downvote your answer.

Comment: @Julian - ok, we are good. I apologize for assuming you down voted the answer. And thanks for the clarification on links.